# Reloading data using Ajax and dataTables at the end of pagination

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am trying to write a script using dataTables which displays a number of rows of data in a loop.
I have the script working apart from on part, I need the ajax call to execute atfer the last row of data has been displayed.
I have tried using table.ajax.reload() at the end of the loop but that just causes only the first page to display.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```js
var airlineimage = '../../';
var pageInfo;
var pageLength;
var endInt;
var currentInt;
$(document).ready( function () {
  table = $('#fidsTable').DataTable( {  
    ajax: {
      url: 'get_fids.php', 
      dataSrc: '',
    },
    pageLength: 5, 
    responsive: true,
    ordering: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    paging: true,
    searching: false,
    orderable: false,
    info : false, 
    dom: '<"top"i>rt><"clear">',
    dom: '<"bottom"i>rt<"clear">',
    language: {
       "emptyTable": "There are no flights for <?php echo $date; ?>"
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "ScheduleTime", width: '7%'},
      { 
        data: "Image",
        width: '20%',
        render : function (data, type){
          return '<img src="' + airlineimage + '' +data+'" " />';
        }
      },
      { data: "AirportName",  width: '20%'},
      { data: "Temp",  width: '20%'},
      { data: "Flight",  width: '12%'},
      { data: "RemarksWithTime", width: '11%'},
    ],
    rowCallback: function(row, data){ 
      $('td:eq(1)', row).find("span").css({color: "blue" });
    },
    // START OF LOOP
    initComplete: function(settings, json){ 
      pageInfo = table.page.info(),
      endInt = pageInfo.end,
      // Current page
      currentInt = 0,
      interval = setInterval(function(){
      table.page( currentInt ).draw( 'page' );
      currentInt++;
      console.log("CURRENT", currentInt);
      console.log("ENDINT", endInt);
      if ( currentInt ===  endInt)
        currentInt = 0;
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds
  } <--- extra closing curly brace ???
    // END OF LOOP
  });
});
```

Comment: So I tried to reformat your code to fix the indentation and I think you might have an extra closing curly brace near the end after your initComplete.

Comment: @mark_b Hi, I have checked the code and the curly brace is required. Without it the script does not run. That said, many thanks for looking at the post.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by changing the code, see below.

```
// START OF LOOP
  initComplete: function(settings, json){ 
    pageInfo = table.page.info(),
    endInt = pageInfo.end,
    // Current page
    currentInt = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    table.page( currentInt ).draw( 'page' );
    currentInt++;
    if ( currentInt ===  endInt)
      currentInt = 0;
      if ( currentInt == 0) { // NEW CODE START
        table.ajax.reload();
    }                        // NEW CODE END
    }, 6000); // 3 seconds
   }
   // END OF LOOP
```